# operation of std_logic:='X'

Tags: vhdl

**The summarized question is at the bottom.**

I'm analyzing and studying the existing VHDL code.
In this code, **port  reset_i was initialized to 'X'** as you can see in below code.

```
entity ADC_fsm is
Port ( clk_i                :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       reset_i              :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       di_req_i             :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       wr_ack_i             :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       spi_ssel_i           :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       reg_enable_i         :   in  std_logic := 'X';
       reg_data_i           :   in  std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
       adc_data_i           :   in  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
       bitslip_o            :   out std_logic;
       sync_done_o          :   out std_logic; 
       wr_en_o              :   out std_logic;
       spi_data_o           :   out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0')
      );
end ADC_fsm;
```

This port (reset_i) was not connected with other external port or signal.

And in next code,

```
begin
process(clk_i, reset_i)
    begin
        if (reset_i = '1') then
            wr_en_o       <= '0';
            sync_done_o   <= '0';
            bitslip_o     <= '0';
            spi_data_o    <= (others => '0');

        s_delay_count     <= 0;
        s_write_indicator <= 0;

            state       <= ready;

        elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then

        wr_en_o       <= '0';
            sync_done_o   <= '0';
            bitslip_o     <= '0';
```

I know that 'X' is neither 1 nor 0.
so, first if statement in above code won't work.

My question is how about elsif.

'X' is not '1', so 'X' included in elsif situation?

**In short.**

```
if (reset_i ='1') then
(A)
elsif(rising_edge(clk_i)) then
(B)
end if;
```

Does code (B) work only when reset_i = '0'?
or also work when reset_i ='X'?

THANKs

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators "The equality and inequality operators (= and /=) are defined for all types other than file types and protected types. The equality operator returns the value TRUE if the two operands are equal and returns the value FALSE otherwise. The inequality operator returns the value FALSE if the two operands are equal and returns the value TRUE otherwise."
Two scalar values of the same type are equal if and only if the values are the same.

Comment: Your last code snippet isn't valid VHDL lacking a condition (an expression with a Boolean value) to be evaluated between the reserved words elsif and then. rising_edge is a function that requires a transition from '0' or 'L' to '1' or 'H' to return TRUE. Lacking a use clause, presumably found in package ieee.std_logic_1164.

Comment: @user1155120 i modified last code!.

Comment: If reset is 'X' then clock branch is taken.  Vhdl code is very explicit. If you want reset to be '0' with clk, you need to say so.  NOTE 'X' cannot exist in real hardware

Answer (score 5):

The type `std_logic` is an *enumeration type* with 9 values and has the following 9 values:

```
'U','X','0','1','Z','W','L','H','-'
```

Each value is just a distinct, arbitrary symbol. So, the line

```
if reset_i ='1' then            -- the brackets are not required
```

will be true if and only if `reset_i` equals `'1'`. That's it. `'X'` is just a different, arbitrary symbol.